# why can't change iframe height from jquery inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a problem iframe like code below. When i reload a browser, iframe height still in 100px. i want to change iframe height 500px.

```
<iframe style="height:100px" width="100%" id="parentiframe">
  <head><script src="/mobile/themes/2015/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#parentiframe").css({"height":"500px"});
    });
  </script>
</iframe>
```

I try like that but it doesn't work.
how to change parentiframe to 500px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<iframe style="height:100px" width="100%" id="parentiframe">
  <head><script src="/mobile/themes/2015/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#parentiframe", window.parent.document).css({"height":"500px"});
    });
  </script>
</iframe>
```

Ofcourse both documents should have same domain, otherwise is not possible due to security issues